# Plotting overlay of another column of data in seaborn with less mentions but duplicate graph values

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn

I can't find a way to word my issue properly in the header so I'm going to explain it a bit better, I'm making a swarm plot in seaborn, on the Y axis is Sentiment, on the X axis is a symbol, a symbol is mentioned a certain number of times and so it gets pushed out to show a larger spread of mentions on the x axis, I'm trying to overlay another column of data of 'Avg. Sentiment' I only need the point plotted once but since the average technically goes with the number of mentions it creates essentially a line on the graph where the avg would be, it's like a duplicate value almost.
[image]

as you can see I only need the value once, I can't just end up using some sort of function to plot an average from pandas or seaborn because I plan on using a custom weighted average point that's already been made

here is the code to output and test the graph

```
np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Symbol': ['AMC', 'GME', 'BB', 'SPY', 'SPCE'],
    'Mentions': [100, 75, 50, 25, 20],
    'Avg.Sentiment':[.8,.7,.6,.5,.4]
})

df['Sentiment'] = df['Mentions'].apply(lambda x: (np.random.random(x) * 2) - 1)
df = df.explode('Sentiment')


pos = [0.0, 1.0]
colors = ['#FF5000', '#00C805']
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("",list(zip(pos,colors)))
matplotlib.cm.register_cmap("newmap", cmap)
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(32,14)})
sns.set(font_scale=2.0)

dplot = sns.swarmplot(x="Symbol", y="Avg.Sentiment", color='black', data=df, marker='X', size=10)
dplot= sns.swarmplot(x="Symbol", y="Sentiment", hue='Sentiment',palette="newmap", data=df)

dplot.get_legend().remove()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, just using plt.scatter you can enter in single points from the same data frame, so in my case

```
plt.scatter(x="Symbol", y="Avg.Sentiment", data=df, color='black', marker='X')
```